# Link to Homepage in Menu

Tags: menus, pages, links, homepage

I am using the mh-newsdesk-lite wordpress theme in [one of my client's websites](http://bambakids.com/michalzucker/) and I'd like to have a link to the homepage in the menu.

It ideally would be accomplished without php, or without any code, but I've been looking and I do **not** want to make my homepage static, as I have latest posts there.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the following steps

1. Go to You Dashboard
2. Click Appearance > Menus
3. Under Pages, Click View All
4. There will be a 'Home' option
5. Check that Home Option
6. Click 'Add to Menu'
7. The new Menu item will appear in the right block
8. Drag the home menu to the top
9. Save the menu

[image]